# Evergreen turning yellow

Tags: diagnosis, evergreens

After some weeks away we came back and found our pine trees getting yellow. It starts from the outside and at the moment there are not many brown branches/needles.

I read it could be manganese deficiency, or the cold weather (we have been told it was freezing in the south in our absence). I will appreciate any comments as we are quite new and my dad (the gardener) passed away last year.

[image: Pine - https://www.flickr.com/photos/9050012@N04/shares/KGk8qh]

Comment: Sorry I tried to use flickr to upload a picure without sucess. If it helps I will copy it here: https://www.flickr.com/photos/9050012@N04/shares/KGk8qh  aparently the frost was short, the trees are in a sunny part for about 3-4 years in yhe same place, without any replanting in the middle. Thanks!

Comment: In my Android phone under chrome browser it does load but Add Picture only load and does not go anywhere else.

Comment: But pine wilt is not widely spread like Portugal... I couldn't find any outbreak here in UK. The tree was not prune in all these years, there is no logs or cuts and the pine was growing quite healthy. Do you know which nutrients do this type of tree be lacking?

Comment: Sorry!! My mistake, we are in the south of England, an inland town called Crawley.

Comment: The picture is not of a pine tree, looks more like a cedar  also called arborvitae

Comment: Thank you so much for all your answers! Didn't know which "pine" I had, I will look for more information about nutrients and deseases more accurately,  I will trim them in the following days! Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this in the North (Wisconsin and Minnesota) quite often. It looks like your "Pine", which may be an Arborvitae (White Cedar) may have experienced winter burn. The fact that your tree is planted in a pot makes it susceptible to winter burn because of its shallow root system. The browning occurs when the plant might try to transpire in the sun, but it cannot replace the water it is losing because the soil is frozen.

You can prune out the dead foliage about now since new foliage may be emerging.

[See example photo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=arborvitae%20winter%20burn&t=ffsb&iax=1&ia=images&iai=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.arbordoctor.net%2Fwinter-burn-umn.jpg)